# Find volume under given contraints on the Cartesian plane.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

The constrains are given as

$$x^2+y^2+z^2 \leqslant 64,\,x^2+y^2\leqslant 16,\,x^2+y^2\leqslant z^2,\,z\geqslant 0\,.$$

With the goal of finding the Volume.
Personally, I have trouble interpreting the constrains in terms of integrals to find the Volume. However, logically z can be maximum of 8
and x or y no larger than 4.

Comment: You could write this $x^2+y^2\le \min(16, z^2, 64-z^2)$ with $z\in [0, 8]$

Comment: What tools are at your disposal?  This is snap with a triple integral.  Short of that, we can set this up as volume of revolution problem.  At the most simplistic, we break up the region into a cone, a cylinder and a spherical cap.  Each of these has a formula you can look-up.

Comment: The first constrain concerns the sphere of radius 8, the second concerns the circle of radius 4, and the third one concerns the cone with a maximum height of 8, if you think about it in terms of set, take the intersection of the three sets and you obtain the region where you want to integrate.

Comment: Sure, i can solve it via computer. But, I got such question on the exam this year and we had only pen and paper. I would really appreciate if you help me understand how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simpler if you convert to [cylindrical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system). In this coordinate system, we have $\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $z=z$, and $\phi=\textrm{arctan}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ (sort of - see the wikipedia article for a better explanation of how $\phi$ relates to $x$ and $y$). An important point is that $\rho$ is taken to be positive, while $\phi$ dictates direction completely.

Under this system, we have the bounds $\rho^2+z^2\leq 64, \rho^2\leq 16, \rho^2\leq z^2, z\geq 0$. From these inequalities, we have that $z$ may range anywhere from $0$ to $8$, and there is no restriction on $\phi$ (so it ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$). Combining the inequalities involving $\rho$, we get that as $z$ ranges from $0$ to $4$, $\rho$ ranges from $0$ to $z$. Then, as $z$ ranges from $4$ to $\sqrt{48}$, $\rho$ ranges from $0$ to $4$. Finally, as $z$ ranges from $\sqrt{48}$ to $8$, $\rho$ ranges from $0$ to $\sqrt{64-z^2}$.

We can write each of these three volumes as triple integrals. The volume element in cylindrical coordinates, $dV$, is $\rho\;d\rho\;dz\;d\phi$. So the first will be

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4\int_0^z 1\times \; \rho\;d\rho\;dz\;d\phi$$$

Similarly the second will be $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_4^{\sqrt{48}}\int_0^4 1\times \; \rho\;d\rho\;dz\;d\phi$$

and the third will be $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\sqrt{48}}^8\int_0^{\sqrt{64-z^2}} 1\times \; \rho\;d\rho\;dz\;d\phi$$

Solve each triple integral from the inside out, add the three together, and you'll have your answer.

(feel free to comment or edit for any correction or suggestion)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you share some thoughts on how to choose phi.

Comment: @PavelFedotov Right. Essentially, all the constraints in the question involve 'distance-like' terms. Like $x^2+y^2$ or $x^2+y^2+z^2$. But no constraint makes any restriction as to the direction of a point inside the volume (relative to the $z$-axis). From this we conclude that any angle $\phi$ is allowed, so the range of $\phi$ is the complete interval $[0,2\pi)$. Visually, this means that the volume is rotationally symmetric/ cylindrically symmetric about the $z$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Split the volume into three parts:  cone, cylinder, and spherical cap:

[image: volume]

The formulas for these three-dimensional figures are well known:

$$V_{cone} = \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h$$

$$V_{cylinder} = \pi r^2 h$$

$$V_{cap} = \frac{1}{3} \pi a^2 (3 R - a)$$

where $R$ is the radius of the sphere and $a$ is the distance between the plane "cutting" the cap and the center of the sphere.

All these variables are found easily through simple high-school algebra.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what is a and R in this example?is it 4 and 4?